# Can I update my system with a Live CD?

Tags: updates, live-cd

I've installed Ubuntu from a Live CD in VMWare, After that I configured everything for my need and of course I installed some additional tools. Everything works fine, But regularly I receive a new Live CD with updated software and some new installed tools which I need to use.
Is it possible to update Ubuntu with the new Live CD? Else I have always to reconfigure and install my personal stuff from scratch.

I'm also interested in a solution which need some action on the "Live CD-Producer", But of course if there is something that I can do, This will be preferred.

Comment: so you mean to upgrade your system with all the applications and tools you installed unchanged and remain there?

Comment: Ref: @ashutosh / When you say you have an Ubuntu Live CD installed in VMWare, you installed Ubuntu from the Live CD as a Virtual machine in VMWare. I think you should be able to achieve  what you want simply by using the Software Updater which you can access from the little 'gear wheel' icon in the top right of the Ubuntu screen. Are you receiving new Live CDs by post??

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the cd, a window like this should come out, PS: This is an old screenshot, i expect that the 12.04 is the same, you should choose the upgrade option.

I hope that works

http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_1QSDkzYY2vc/TWzh8Z786xI/AAAAAAAADNw/8lXqgCMgicY/ubuntu11.04-installer.png